# How to collaborate with teammate on code more efficiently?

Tags: python, collaboration

I encounter some problems when collaborate with my teammate on some Python project. There are some difference between the usage of the function. For example, we want to read the xlsx file, `pd.read_excel(f'D:\\Financial\\Data\\TRD_Dalyr.xlsx')`, this works on my computer but not on my teammate, and `pd.read_excel('.\Data\TRD_Dalyr.xlsx')` works for his computer but not mine. So every time, he modify the file and send back to me, I have to fix those problem. Is there a more efficient way to deal with this kind of problem?

Comment: use a config/.env file for stating where the file is.

Comment: Maybe a `try`, `except` block? Or use an environmental variable?